# Sort column headers in wpf datagrid from xaml

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, xaml, datagrid

```
public DataTable Data
{
    get { return _tableData; }
    set
    {
        if (Equals(value, _tableData)) return;
        _tableData = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange();
    }   
}
```

And I have my xaml datagrid:

```
<DataGrid
  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
  IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" 
  AutoGenerateColumns="True">
</DataGrid>
```

Lets say, there is a `DataTable` will next columns:

- B Column
- A Column
- D Column
- C Column

I need a way to represent them in alphabetical order via `xaml`:

- A Column
- B Column
- C Column
- D Column

What I already tried:

1. Collection view source with sortable property:

> ```
> <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ColumnsDatagridViewSource" Source="{Binding Data}">
>     <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
>         <componentModel:SortDescription PropertyName="ColumnHeader"/>
>     </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
> </CollectionViewSource>
> ```

Does not help, an array occured. It tries to find this property in column header string.

1. IValue converter, which helped me with treeview sorting:

> ```
> public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
> {
>    System.Collections.IList collection = value as System.Collections.IList;
>    ListCollectionView view = new ListCollectionView(collection);
>    SortDescription sort = new SortDescription(parameter.ToString(), ListSortDirection.Ascending);
>    view.SortDescriptions.Add(sort);
>
>    return view;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Since you're auto generating columns, I think the best way to do it is using the [DataGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratingcolumn(v=vs.110).aspx).

I came up with this code--**careful, not fully tested**--to reorder the columns in alphabetical order:

**XAML**

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Data}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="True"
          AutoGeneratingColumn="dg_AutoGeneratingColumn" />
```

**Code-behind**

```
public class DataItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Ask { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Zulu { get; set; }
    public DataItem(string n, string a, string d, string z)
    {
        Name = n;
        Ask = a;
        Date = d;
        Zulu = z;
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ObservableCollection<DataItem> data = new ObservableCollection<DataItem>();
    public ObservableCollection<DataItem> Data
    {
        get
        {
            return data;
        }
    }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        Data.Add(new DataItem("A", "No", "07/14", "?"));
        Data.Add(new DataItem("B", "Yes", "07/14", "!"));
        Data.Add(new DataItem("C", "Tes", "07/14", "*"));
        Data.Add(new DataItem("D", "No", "07/14", "%"));
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    private void dg_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid dg = sender as DataGrid;
        if (dg != null && e != null)
        {
            DataGridColumn currentColumn = e.Column;
            if (currentColumn != null)
            {
                string currentHeader = currentColumn.Header.ToString();

                int currentIndex = 0;

                // Sort the Columns by name so we add the new column to the correct index
                foreach (DataGridColumn dgc in (dg.Columns.OrderBy(col => col.Header.ToString())))
                {
                    if (currentHeader.CompareTo(dgc.Header.ToString()) < 0)
                    {
                        // set the current columns
                        currentColumn.DisplayIndex = currentIndex;

                        // short-circuit the loop so we don't keep comparing after we already
                        // found the correct index to place the current column
                        break;
                    }

                    currentIndex++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output without using `dg_AutoGeneratingColumn`:

[image: Output without using dg_AutoGeneratingColumn]

Output using `dg_AutoGeneratingColumn`:

[image: Output using dg_AutoGeneratingColumn]

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested in how I did it:

```
<DataGrid
  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
  IsReadOnly="True"
  IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Data, Converter={StaticResource DataGridSortingConverter}}" 
  AutoGenerateColumns="True">
</DataGrid>
```

I added `IValueConverter` for sorting, nothing special and needs refactoring, but you can get an idea:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value == null)
                return null;

            var dataTable = value as DataTable;

            if (dataTable != null)
            {
                var columnsList = (from object column in dataTable.Columns select column.ToString()).ToList();

                columnsList = columnsList.OrderBy(col => col).ToList();

                for (var i = 0; i < columnsList.Count; i++)
                {
                    dataTable.Columns[columnsList[i]].SetOrdinal(i);
                }

                return dataTable;
            }

            return value;
        }
```

What this code does:

First I get column names from datatable and then sort them in order I need.
Next, I use built-in `SetOrdinal` method on column, which puts it in right position.